# TFS 2018 upgrade error Issue=icon_traffic_cone

Tags: tfs, upgrade

I am upgrading TFS 2015 Update 3 to 2018 Update 2. Overall everything works fine but with one project particularly I am not able to access Work tab. When running process template update wizard then the below warnings and an error pop up. TFS finds Agile template as the closest suitable one.

> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work item type 'Task'
>   because the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Task' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork' to the work item type 'Bug' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] TF400609: Cannot add the action
>   'Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork' to the work item type 'Bug' because
>   the state 'New' does not exist.
>
> [Warning] VS402404: Bugs On TaskBoard: Bug does not have the
>   Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity field defined. Some charts will not
>   include these work item types.
>
> [Warning] VS402404: Bugs On TaskBoard: Bug does not have the
>   Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork field defined. Some charts
>   will not include these work item types.
>
> [Warning] TF400607: Category 'Microsoft.HiddenCategory' will be
>   overwritten.
>
> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following
>   element contains an error: Properties. This element defines the
>   properties for this team project. The value of the 'WorkItemTypeIcons'
>   property is invalid. VS403291: Invalid work item type in pair
>   'Issue=icon_traffic_cone'.

What needs to be done to fix this problem correctly? I understand how to create new process template, but would like to confirm if the default Agile template is broken in TFS 2018 after upgrade and whether it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I haven't found much information online and post resolution steps below, for the benefit of community.

There were two unusual issues with this project. It is an old project which migrated from several previous versions of TFS, and it also had template process customizations. This prevented process template from being updated automatically.

Solutions steps are:

1) Download Agile Process from TFS 2018

2) Export all necessary definitions from the "The Problem Project" project. This showed a number of errors. For example ProcessConfiguration was not defined, FeedbackRequest was not defined, etc. To get these errors run the following commands and look inside exported files:

```
witadmin.exe exportcategories /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/FRTS_Projects/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\categories.xml"
witadmin.exe exportprocessconfig /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/FRTS_Projects/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\processconfig.xml" 

witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\bug.xml" /n:"bug"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\codereviewrequest.xml" /n:"code review request"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\codereviewresponse.xml" /n:"code review response"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Epic.xml" /n:"epic"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\feature.xml" /n:"feature"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\feedbackrequest.xml" /n:"feedback request"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\feedbackresponse.xml" /n:"feedback response"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\issue.xml" /n:"issue"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Sharedparameter.xml" /n:"Shared parameter"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\SharedStep.xml" /n:"Shared Step"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Task.xml" /n:"Task"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Testcase.xml" /n:"test case"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\testplan.xml" /n:"test plan"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\testsuite.xml" /n:"test suite"
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\user story.xml" /n:"user story"
```

3) Import missing definitions from the Agile process:

```
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\codereviewrequest.xml" 
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\codereviewresponse.xml" 
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Epic.xml" 
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\feature.xml"
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\feedbackrequest.xml" 
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\feedbackresponse.xml" 
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\issue.xml"
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Sharedparameter.xml"
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\SharedStep.xml"
```

4) Import processconfig and categories, also from the Agile process:

```
witadmin.exe importcategories /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\categories.xml"
witadmin.exe importprocessconfig /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\Process\processconfiguration.xml"
```

5) Step 4 showed additional errors which prevented the import**. This is was caused by our customizations of Agile process. Fix the errors in existing process UserStory.xml and Bug.xml and re-import definitions:

```
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\UserStory.xml"
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://tfsonprem:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/" /p:"The Problem Project" /f:"C:\TFSFix\Bug.xml"
```

Also fix process configuration***

6) Repeat Step 4. Both commands must run without errors

That's it.

=======

** One new field was missing in UserStory.xml and Bug.xml

```
<FIELD name="Value Area" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" type="String">
        <REQUIRED />
        <ALLOWEDVALUES>
          <LISTITEM value="Architectural" />
          <LISTITEM value="Business" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="Business" />
        <HELPTEXT>The type should be set to Business primarily to represent customer-facing issues. Work to change the architecture should be added as a User Story</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
```

*** There were customizations which are just our isolated case and probably not relevant for community. Just for a record, process configuration also needed some updates to states:

```
  <TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <States>
      <State value="Active" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="In QA" type="InProgress" />   
      <State value="In Review" type="InProgress" />   
      <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
    </States>
```

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2018 has the new form compare with the old version TFS 2015 ....

Based on the warning and error messages, you need to custom the process template to fix that:

The error `TF400654` and warning `TF400609` are mentioned in Microsoft document : [Resolve errors received when configuring features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913787.aspx), please try the related solution:

1. [Export process configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx) using **witadmin**
   exportprocessconfig.
2. Change the `States` elements and add the missing field or state to match your work items states.
3. Then [export categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273721.aspx) and all categories matches your workflow
   requirements.
4. Finally import them after changes.

For the error `VS403291` icon issue, you can reference below blog for troubleshooting:

- [TFS 2017 Update 2 RC2 and work item type icons](https://blogs.like10.com/2017/07/21/tfs-2017-update-2-rc2-and-work-item-type-icons/)

Comment: Hi Andy, it seems like there is a problem with export process function. Exported file cannot get re-imported, with error message "Line: 3 Position: 4 - The required attribute 'category' is missing." Export returns just this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <RequirementBacklog workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel />
  </RequirementBacklog>
  <TaskBacklog workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <AddPanel />
  </TaskBacklog>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="BugsBehavior" value="Off" />
  </Properties>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>

Comment: @lekso The message explicitly pointed that `"Line: 3 Position: 4 - The required attribute 'category' is missing."` You need to debug based on the error message...

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I export processConfiguration and it comes out as in my previous comment. I cannot re-import it because it is broken

Comment: Yeah, I see, that's because it has the `Process Validation` mechanism, the process of course has problems as it's upgraded from old version to new and apply for the new features you need to custom and debug the process accordingly... Please see [Process Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/migration-processtemplates?view=vsts) and [Configure features after an upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/configure-features-after-upgrade?view=vsts) for details.

Comment: Hi Andy. I posted solution. It is logical, but with lack of proper resolution guide hopefully it'll be useful to someone else